# React onSubmit function doesn't hit Express endpoint (Nodemailer)

Tags: reactjs, express, nodemailer

I have a form, which submits `name`, `email` and `text`.

onSubmit function of the React component:

```
    onSubmit = e => {
    const { name, email, text } = this.state;

    axios.post('/feedback', { name, email, text })
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
          }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

feedback.js file (api/feedback.js - this works fine and sends email if requested via Postman):

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// @route   POST api/feedback
// @desc    Tests resource route
// @access  Public
router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
  let output = `<p>New feedback</p>
  <h3>Feedback details</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
    <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Feedback message</h3>
  <p>${req.body.text}</p>
`;

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: "t4qj6mgea2kpyep7@ethereal.email",
      pass: "PASSWORD"
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnathorized: false
    }
  });

  let mailOptions = {
    from: 'Webtool feedback: <t4qj6mgea2kpyep7@ethereal.email>', // sender address
    to: "TO@EMAIL.COM", // list of receivers
    subject: 'Feedback from Webtool', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world', // plain text body
    html: output // html body
  };
  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have imported this into App.js, and set up the route for the feedback:

```
const feedback = require('./routes/api/feedback');
```

The issue is that the **endpoint itself works**, if I use Postman, I successfully receive an e-mail, so I don't suspect the `feedback.js` file. However, `onSubmit()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

​Did you make sure to include the middleware to protect web servers?

--Try this--

```
//middleware meant to protect web servers [CORS requests]
//can change '*' to 'http://localhost:3000' for local host testing

app.use((request, response, next) => {
 response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
 next();
 app.use(bodyParser.json())
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded){
 extended: false
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the form to `/feedback` as a post request but in the server side you you are having a post method with route `/`.So,The route `/feedback` is not in the express and so it throwed you 404 not found.Try changing the server route to `/feedback`.

Comment: That is not the case, since I am using Router(), and the file feedback.js on server is itself the path. So if I specify /feedback, it would have been feedback/feedback.